# boost library multithread socket strangeness

Tags: multithreading, boost

I've been stuck for a whole night but can't figure out the problem.

I'm writing a server that accepts connections for a chatroom application. The idea is that the server gives the connected sockets to chat_manager, chat_manager puts them in a waitlist and starts a thread to constantly check if somebody is still in the waitlist. If somebody is in the waitlist, the chat_manager tries to read from the client to determine which room the client wants to join.

main.cpp looks like this :

```
boost::asio::io_service io_service;
chat_server server(io_service, 8091);
io_service.run();
```

Chat server code :

```
chat_server::chat_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, int port) : io_service_(io_service), 
    acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)) {
    start_accept();
}
void chat_server::start_accept() {
    chat_session_ptr new_session(new chat_session(io_service_));

    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(), boost::bind(&chat_server::handle_accept, this, new_session, 
        boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
void chat_server::handle_accept(chat_session_ptr s, const boost::system::error_code& error) {
    if (!error) {       // successfully connected
        chat_manager::Instance().chat_session_join(s);
    }

    start_accept();
}
```

chat_manager is simply

```
chat_manager() { // constructor
    waitlist_.resize(0);
    manager_thread_ = boost::thread(&chat_manager::run, this);
}

int chat_session_join(chat_session_ptr chat_session) {
    mutex_.lock();
    waitlist_.push_back(chat_session);
    mutex_.unlock();
    return 1;
}

void run() {
    while (1) {
        mutex_.lock();
        for (auto &s : waitlist_) {
            std::string roomname;
            if (s->wait_for_join(roomname)) {
                ...
            }

            break;
        }
        mutex_.unlock();

        boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10) );
    }
}
```

And session.cpp :

```
jsoncons::json chat_session::receive_request(boost::system::error_code& error) {

    buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());

    size_t bytes_transferred;
    boost::system::error_code ec = boost::asio::error::would_block;

    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, buffer_, "\n", 
            boost::bind(&chat_session::handle_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2, &ec, &bytes_transferred ));

    deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));
    deadline_.async_wait(boost::bind(&chat_session::check_deadline, shared_from_this()));

    do pio_service_->run_one(); while (ec == boost::asio::error::would_block);

    std::cout << "got it" << std::endl;

    if ( ec || !socket_.is_open() ) {
        std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
        return jsoncons::json();
    }

    std::istream is(&buffer_);

    return jsoncons::json::parse(is);
}

int chat_session::wait_for_join(std::string &roomname) {
    boost::system::error_code error;
    jsoncons::json request = receive_request(error);
    ...
}

void chat_session::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred, 
    boost::system::error_code* out_error, size_t* out_bytes_transferred) {

    deadline_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);

    *out_error = error;
    *out_bytes_transferred = bytes_transferred;

    if (!error) {
    } else {
        std::cout << "handle_read error:" << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

What happens is, 
1. when the client connects and doesn't send anything, the connection is closed by the server after 2 seconds. which is correct. but
2. if the client sends one string before the connection expires, the server worked its way into handle_read but never gets past pio_service->run_one();
3. if the client send another string, wait_for_join will finish and the run() procedure starts to loop.

To me it seems that the use of io_services here is fine because check_deadline and handle_read worked, but if that really worked it would modify ec != would_block, and the do-while loop should return. What's happening here? I'm really confused.

Comment: At a rough guess you are expecting a io_service created and running in  in the main line to ALSO operate inside a thread. They don't.

The short answer is why are you bothering to use a thread? You have a complete event system already running in io_service. Just let it run(), drop the spurious and excessive use of threads, and just use the async handlers for the incoming and outgoing comms.

Comment: It's actually my first time writing a server, so I'm not sure how it's usually done. Eventually I want each chatroom to run on its own so if one crashes the server won't crash. But I know of no way to hand a established socket to another program so I decided to use threads instead. Once I hand the sockets to a chatroom, the chatroom should handle the communications, not the server.

Comment: I read somewhere that it's fine to use a single io_service in multiple threads, and since in my main.cpp it keeps accepting new connections, run() never terminates and is always valid. But in the thread I called run_one() which seems to block for some unknown reason even though the jobs are completed (handle_read).

My guess now is that the main thread's io_service_.run() handled the handle_read job, but receive_request's run_one() didn't get notified so it was blocked in the while loop waiting for another event.

Comment: Replacing run_one() with sleep(10) solves it.

Comment: It would. A sleep(0) would do the same thing - allow a context switch to the main thread. Try it out - it would show the actual polling overhead as a core hits 100%. Because of the way that threads effectively use the shared memory space, your threads are accessing data in the main thread and attached to the io_service. They also do most of their work (ie io) in the main thread. You'd actually be safer if they weren't in a thread. All you have really done is add the extra complexity of protecting data with mutexes